# mongodb query based on multiple properties of the document which returns an array of objects that contain the count of each property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql-aggregation

I am working on a **nodeJS** application using **MongoDB** and I am struggling to construct a query. I have gone through the MongoDB documentation and the [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) concept, but still failing to manage it.

So, I have a collection of `Item` documents like this:

```
Item schema -> { id: number, status: string, category: string, subCategory: string }

E.g.:

[
...
{
  id: 38219388214034,
  status: 'inStock',
  category: 'Food',
  subCategory: 'Sweet'
},
{
  id: 18371917455611,
  status: 'pending',
  category: 'Accessories',
  subCategory: 'Other'
}
...
]
```

The `status` can have only one of the three states: `inStock`, `outOfStock`, and `pending`.
The `subCategory` has the following relation with the `category` (which is another collection, the `Category` collection):

```
Category schema -> { category: string, subCategory: Array<string> }

E.g.:

[
  ...
  { category: 'Food', subCategory: ['Sour', 'Sweet', 'Other'] },
  { category: 'Sports', subCategory: ['T-Shirt', 'Shorts', 'Ball', 'Other'] },
  { category: 'Accessories', subCategory: ['Drill Bits', 'Screws', 'Fluids', 'Other'] }
  ...    
 ]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to create a query that returns an array of objects that contain the count of each subcategory related to its category, like:

| subcategory | category | inStock | outOfStock | pending | items in total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sour | Food | 12 | 1 | 3 | 16 |
| Other | Food | 20 | 8 | 12 | 40 |
| Other | Accessories | 42 | 12 | 17 | 71 |

My closest attempt to that, but still wrong, is the following:

```
const categories = await Categories.find();
let toMatch = [];

categories.forEach(category => {
    toMatch.push({ $and: [{ categoryName: category.categoryName }, { subCategories: category.subCategories }] });
});

const itemsCount = await Item.aggregate([
  { $match: toMatch },
  { $group: { _id: '$status', count: { $sum: 1 }} }
]);
```

**Any help is more than appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `$group` by both `category` and `subCategory` and for this, so the results are one document with all `status` options per each `category` and `subCategory` pair:

**EDIT**:

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        subCategory: "$subCategory",
        category: "$category"
      },
      totalCount: {$sum: 1},
      pending: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$status", "pending"]}, 1, 0]}},
      inStock: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$status", "inStock"]}, 1, 0]}},
      outOfStock: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$status", "outOfStock"]}, 1, 0]}}
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wFa2w5H67pV)

Comment: wow! you are really fast and correct also ;-D exactly what I need!
works great! thanks also for the MongoDB playground, I didn't know it and it's very useful

Comment: After a while of using your query, I figured out a small issue...
When there are two `categories` with a `subcategory` that have the same name, then the count occurs at the first `category` occurrence and every `subcategory` is added to this one.

You can have a look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UqZdoTrDx3b)

Comment: You are right. Updated accordingly